# Does google api support get user space name/id by using email address?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have a scenario which application will send an email address and expecting user information in return including space id/name.

the name space/id will be use as identifier to send back other information on that particular user.

I know by using service account is possible to retrieved space name/id but is there any api can use to retrieve space name/id by using email address.

this is example [get name space/id](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list)

kindly share method/google api that can be use.

Here is sample nodejs code and it will return members object:

```
var endpoint = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/*****/members'
var options =   {
method: 'GET',
json: true,
uri: endpoint,
headers:{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-type":"application/json",
  "Authorization":"Bearer "+accessToken
}

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
console.log(body);});
```

Note: Do not have G suite account.

Comment: PLease edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: @DaImTo i have updated my question and sample of code.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that you would be able to search on an unauthorized users email address?

Comment: Very sorry, I still am not understanding, please confirm: you want to call the Google Chat API with a users email address and not their ID. Right?

Comment: @DaImTo lets say the users already in the same domain . can it be done?

Comment: @iansedano yes, by using a users email address to retrieved information on that user example space name.

Comment: @DaImTo I could not found a document to make a process flow connected between search using user email address then can get user space name.

Comment: The only way that i know of to get information about the current authenticated user is to include the profile scope and either go through the userinfo endpoint or the google people api.  The latter being the most reliable option.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not possible using the chat API or any other.

The API is directed towards making bots and so there is large potential for spam. It is unlikely that there will be a way to do this, though you can request it with the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).